# Does (int i = 0; i < n; i++;) used as a block instead of {int i = 0; i < n; i++;} make any sense at all in C?

Tags: c, block, parentheses, curly-brackets

Don't know if it's a really dumb thing to ask as I feel it goes against C syntax.But I am not sure.I stumbled across that in a question posted few minutes back.The OP uses something like `(int i = 0; i < n; i++)`, ie without even a `;` after `i++`.

[Fibonacci Series in C - The series of numbers up to a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303153/fibonacci-series-in-c-the-series-of-numbers-up-to-a-given-number/16303951#16303951)

But though the OP's line is obviously wrong, I am tempted to ask something I just don't know- What does the following mean in C :

```
(int i = 0; i < n; i++;)   // Three `;` terminated statements enclosed in ()
```

as the following simply means a block of statements in C:

```
{int i = 0; i < n; i++;}
```

I mean, what does `(int i = 0,n=3; i = n; i++;)`  mean in the following dummy program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
(int i = 0,n=3; i = n; i++;) 
}
```

**Edit** Even that single line sourced from that original question is ridden with errors.So let me ask this independently : What does it do if we enclose multiple  `;` terminated statements within a pair of `()`? If we enclose within `{}` it becomes a block,but what about `()`?

Comment: It probably means the `for` is missing on the front.

Comment: I had to edit the `(int i = 0; i < n; i++;) ` part due to the sheer number of errors even in that (sourced from original question)

Comment: @LeeMeador That I saw in the context of the OP's question.But what does enclosing `;` terminated statements within a pair of `()` mean in C?

Comment: does that even compile?

Comment: @Goodwine Nope,a pile of errors.I should have listened to my intuition before posting it.Enclosing statements just like that within `()` is as undefined and wrong syntax as enclosing them within  a pair of `@` or `[]`.It's all about how much bigger a pile of errors you get!!

Comment: @Goodwine Look at the code in the original question I linked.You'll lose faith in humanity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing.  The parentheses are used in certain situations such as boolean expressions and for loop comprehensions.  You'll get a bunch of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Common for loop construction:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   //code here
}
```

The code

```
{int i = 0; i < 10; i++;}
```

doesn't really do much except set i to 0 and increment it to 1.
I'm not even sure if saying i < 10 is valid outside a condition

Comment: `i < 10` is valid outside a condition, but it returns a value, and it must be assigned to somewhere, else it will give you an error. ie `bool i_less_than_ten = i < 10;`

Comment: @Goodwine I just tried that.Gives no error of that kind.Maybe compiler dependant

Comment: @Goowind Even this gives the output `1,0` that I expected  `printf("%d,%d",i<j,i>j)` if `i` is greater than `j`.How would you explain this Goodwine?

Comment: @SheerFish Whoa, hold it, I said that if you don't assign it somewhere it will give you an error, in my example I'm assigning it to `i_less_than_ten`, and in your example you are using it as arguments, which falls in "assigned to somewhere"

Comment: It is completely allowed by the standard and not an error at all to have an expression just sit on its own. Any decent compiler will both remove it, and also warn you that you probably made a mistake, but it's perfectly legal code and should not generate an *error*, in the strict sense of the word, in **any** conforming compiler.